# Replaced brake booster 1 1/2 years ago &this is the 2nd time now that when useing the break it makes a hissing noise &at times pedalsucks to the floor

Tags: brakes, brake-booster, vacuum-leak

Toyota Camry LE 4 Cylinder 2007.

A year and a 1/2 ago I replaced my brake booster and ever since then (this is the 2nd time now) my brakes don't work very well they make a hissing noise when I apply the brake and at times the brake pedal will suck to the floor.

I don't know if I did not install the new brake booster correctly or what it could be?  The 1st time it happened a friend did something to fix it, but I am not sure what they did. Its been about 6 months now since the 1st time it happened and was fixed til now.

Comment: "at times".. Randomly, or only after a while driving, or as soon as brakes are hot? Does the car brake by itself or it pedal sinks under light pedal force?  Can you pump pedal hard with engine off? ..with engine on? If you pump pedal then start the car, does it sink normally a bit, then stops? Do brakes stop well? Need more details to make a diagnosis.

Comment: I got a new break booster and took old out and the rubber was torn, i have no clue how that happened but went to put new one in and doesn't fit, the auto store messed up (because apparently i needed a 06 instead of 07 which is what the car is) and waiting for it to come in tomorrow morning so im hoping thats the cure. Also do you know if the radiator or break booster have anything to do with a loud noise sounding like it needs to shift gears when i push the gas and i let off and itll go away. Its only when im gradually getting from 25 to 65 .

Comment: A deer ran into my car and ever since seems like more problems are happening, it did crack my radiator which i plan on replacing next.

Comment: Maybe some pulleys in front of the engine that is bent and not spinning smoothly.. Be sure to follow a good manual installing the booster. There's a very tight gap that needs to be adjusted correctly between master cylinder rod and brake booster. Otherwise brakes may self-apply, drag and overheat, or you may get too low pedal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The car has a vacuum leak. It may be within the brake booster, or in an external vacuum hose. There may be a bad connection at some joint in the vacuum plumbing, or the booster's internal diaphragm may have failed.

Comment: Thank you, Im replacing the break booster beings it has a lifetime warranty.  Hoping thats all it is.